# Easy way to show $e^{-x^2}<\frac1{x^2}$ and $e^{-x^2}<\frac1{\sqrt{|x|}}$

Tags: inequality

I'm looking for an easy and basic way to show that

$$e^{-x^2}<\frac1{x^2}$$
and
$$e^{-x^2}<\frac1{\sqrt{|x|}}$$

for $x\neq 0$. I think there must be a simple trick which won't come to my mind right now.

Comment: For the first inequality, you want to show $x^{2} e^{-x^{2}} <1$.  This function is symmetric about the y-axis, is always positive, and takes the value 0 and $x=0$.  Moreover, as $x \to \pm \infty$ the exponential strongly damps the function to zero.  I would suggest taking a derivative.  This will show you where the maxima are.  You can then show that these maxima in the function values are less than one.  I apologize if you don't know calculus, I'm sure there's an easier way I'm not thinking of at the moment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As regards the first one, for $x\not=0$,
$$e^{-x^2}<\frac1{x^2} \Leftrightarrow x^2<1+x^2\leq e^{x^2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2k}}{k!}.$$
For the second one, note that 
$$\sqrt{|x|}\leq \frac{1+|x|}{2}<1+x^2\leq e^{x^2}.$$

Comment: Very elegant! The inequality you use for $\sqrt{|x|}$ follows from the binomic formula $0\leq(1-\sqrt{|x|})^2 = 1 - 2\sqrt{|x|} + |x|$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: @Wauzl Or from the Arithmetic Geometric mean - inequality $\sqrt{1\times|x|}\leq\frac{1+|x|}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for the first.**

It is equivalent to prove that for $x>0$

$$-x <\ln(\frac {1}{x} )$$
or
$$\ln (x)<x .$$

is true if $0 <x \leq 1$ since $\ln x \leq 0$.

Now consider $f (x)=\ln (x)-x $ for $x>1$.

$$f'(x)=\frac {1-x}{x}<0$$
$f $ is decreasing and
$$f (x)<f (1)<0$$

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, you want to prove that $\frac {1}{e^{x^2}} < \frac {1}{x^2}$ which is the same as proving that $e^{x^2}>x^2$.

Divide by $x^2$  $(x\neq0)$ and you get to prove that $\frac {e^{x^2}}{x^2}>1$.
Now you can look at that function, find its minimum and evaluate it, and get that it is bigger than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate $x^2 e^{-x^2 }$ with respect to $x$, we get $2x e^{-x^2}-2x^3 e^{-x^2}=2x(e^{-x^2 }-x^2 e^{-x^2 }$.

By analysis the zeros of this derivative, we found that $x^2 e^{-x^2 }$ attains its maximum at $|x|=1$, in which the relevant image is $\frac{1}{e}<1$.

As $x^2 > 0$ for all $x\neq 0$, we could get the proof of the first inequality. And by the similar method we could get the second one.

Answer (score 0):

For positive $\alpha$, $$e^{-x^2}<|x|^{-2\alpha}=(x^2)^{-\alpha}$$ is equivalent to

$$x^2>\alpha\log x^2$$

or $$t>\alpha\log t.$$

By the study of the function $t/\log t$, which has a minimum at $t=e$, one sees that the inequality holds for all $t>0$ when $\alpha<e$. In particular, with $\alpha=1$ and $\alpha=1/4$.

Comment: I don't think the analysis of $\frac{\log t}t$ is any easier or basic-er than the original problem.

Comment: @Wauzl: are you kidding ? Finding the minimum takes a minute, $1/\log t-1/\log^2t=0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $y \ge 0$, then $y< e^y$, therefore $ye^{-y}<1$, put $y= x^2$ to get the first inequality.

For the second inequality, observe that $$e^{-kx^2}<1, \ \ \forall \ k>0 $$.

Thus multiplying $e^{-3x^2}$ to the inequality $x^2e^{-x^2}<1$ we have,

$$x^2e^{-4x^2}<1$$

Since all the quantities are positive, we have

$$0 <(x^2e^{-4x^2})^{1/4}<1$$

i.e

$$\sqrt{|x|}e^{-x^2}<1 \implies e^{-x^2} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}$$

Comment: Robert Z 's answer was clearly beautiful...this one isn't too bad either...